# How to create navigation column chart in stacked column high chart

Tags: highcharts

We are using Highcharts and highstock library in our application to create a statcked column chart and want to represent the status of the column stacked chart by a navigator column chart. We want to create to navigator column chart in such a way that the navigator column chart will shown data from my own custom series instead of series from main chart depending on value of "baseSeries".

Here, the problem is that even after using series with my own data attribute in navigator column chart, i am still getting a navigator chart with data same as the first series i.e. dafault navigator chart.

Please go through this js fiddle:

```
<code>    http://jsfiddle.net/54v04uxc/10/   </code>
```

I am not getting the issue that is causing the display of default data in navigation chart instead of my custom series with my own data attribute

Comment: I think that you can add your custom series in load event callback function. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/54v04uxc/11/

Answer (score 0):

You should use navigator.series as an object, not as an array: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series